# FreeRTOS vs Linux against single event upsets

Tags: linux, operating-system, rtos

I am working on the on-board computer for a CubeSat. Our computer will be vulnerable to radiation, hence single event upsets, e.g. bit flips are likely to occur. Would a lighter, smaller OS like FreeRTOS bring more stability, robustness and a lower probability of failure over a full-blown Linux operating system?

Answer (score 2):

The probability of a bit error in RAM is a function of time, memory size and radiation density, so a larger memory has a greater probability, and you can fit a FreeRTOS system in much less memory (like 10kb instead of 4Mb).  However the usage rate of the smaller memory is likely much higher - i.e. in a FreeRTOS application, most of the code and data are accessed relatively frequently, while in a Linux deployment, much of it is redundant and if corrupted may never be accessed in any case.

However the question makes little sense for a number of reasons, such as:

1. The effect of a bit-flip event is entirely non-deterministic, any single event it may be benign or catastrophic.  It is impossible to say that a system can tolerate 1 error when you don't know when or where the error will occur.
2. If your system can be implemented on FreeRTOS, why would you even consider Linux?  They are chalk and cheese.  If you need the extensive networking, filesystem, memory management, POSIX API and device support etc. provided by Linux, FreeRTOS is not suited to your application in any case, as you would have to add all that yourself from your own or additional third-party code.  FreeRTOS is only a scheduling kernel, with threading, synchronisation and IPC support and little else.  Conversely if you need hard real-time deterministic behaviour, Linux is unsuited to your application.

Where you might benefit from using an RTOS kernel like FreeRTOS is that it will execute from ROM which may be less prone to the bit-flipping cosmic ray issue - (although the availability of ECC/radiation hardened Flash memory may indicate otherwise).  You still need RAM for R/W data, but at least the code itself will be robust. A typical FreeRTOS system might run in SRAM (possibly in on-chip RAM on a microcontroller) - I don't know whether low density SRAM is less prone to bit-flipping than high-density SDRAM, but I am willing to believe it is.  It is also possible to source *radiation hardened SRAM* in any case.

The solution for a system using SDRAM in such an environment is to use ECC RAM which may largely overcome the problem of data corruption from radiation and non-deterministic system behaviour.  However I would not imagine that even that would be sufficient for space or high-atmosphere applications.

In short the solution is not in the software, it has to be in the hardware, and the lengths you need to go to will depend on the radiation environment your system will be subjected to.  However the selection of a small RTOS kernel allows the selection of hardware to be potentially much wider since it will run on a much wider range of architectures in much smaller memory, perform deterministically, respond to events in fewer cycles and is ROMable.

Comment: Must one specifically chose ECC RAM, or is this a feature that comes with a CPU? For instance, I have an ECC controller on my CPU, does this suffice, or must the RAM explicitly mention that it is ECC RAM?

Comment: You need ECC ram *and* an ECC SDRAM controller.